# Дубликаты в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

В wordpress появились дубликаты записей следующего вида https://maxdizayn.ru/portfolio/loft777-dizayn-internet-magazina/2  https://maxdizayn.ru/portfolio/loft777-dizayn-internet-magazina/3

и тд. Хотя самих страниц в этих записях нет. записи типа:

https://maxdizayn.ru/portfolio/loft777-dizayn-internet-magazina/page/2 
https://maxdizayn.ru/portfolio/loft777-dizayn-internet-magazina/page/3

при этом редиректит на основную страницу поста. all in one "Запретить разбивку страниц для канонических URL'ов" никак не реагирует на это дело. nofollow noindex точно так же.

Как их запретить вообще? или хотя бы вывести из индексации.

Comment: Это не баг, а фича. WordPress так работает, обеспечивая пагинацию в записи при необходимости. Запретить это нельзя. Да и не нужно. Ищите, почему такие сссылки оказались у вас в индексе, и убирайте у источника.

Comment: Тогда может сделать все проще. Была идея сравнивать фактическую ссылку  и ссылку на страничку и если они не сходятся то добавлять nofollow noindex. Но на страницах рубрик, архивных страницах. при get_permalink получал ссылку на первую запись и они отваливаются из индекса. Есть возможность вытащить url именно странички на которой сейчас находишься, чтобы сравнить со старкой в браузере из php

Comment: Ссылок вида `https://maxdizayn.ru/portfolio/loft777-dizayn-internet-magazina/3` на вашем сайте быть не должно, им неоткуда взяться. WP их не генерит, если нет пагинации внутри записи `loft777-dizayn-internet-magazina`. Разберитесь, где, на какой странице сайта такая ссылка появляется и устраняйте в месте появления - это ошибка вашего кода или плагина.

Comment: Тогда почему по этим ссылкам открывается страница?

Comment: Вы опять не поняли. То, что открывается - правильно. Так и должно быть. Но таких ссылок ваш сайт создавать не должен. Если их нет на сайте, то незачем о них заботиться, бот никогда туда не попадёт. Покажите мне страницу вашего сайта, где я могу увидеть ссылку `https://maxdizayn.ru/portfolio/loft777-dizayn-internet-magazina/3`

Comment: @KAGGDesign это  не было большой проблемой до ВП 4,4. Потом в каноникл стала подставляться пагинация. И сколько не говори разрабам о таких косяках - они ничего не понимают и не делают с этим Лечиться только редиректами.

Answer (score 0):

> Как их запретить вообще? или хотя бы вывести из индексации.

Если на сайте вообще не нужно индексирование страниц пагинации, то настройками сео-плагинов.
Если пагинация нужна, тогда только персональными редиректами попавшими, в индекс.

*К сожалению, этот баг разработчики ВП не считают за баг и не исправлю многие годы. :(*